# How to iterate on multiple lines in a for loop in bash?

Tags: bash

I currently have a bash script that looks similar to below:

```
for i in foo_dir/foo_filename.xml,passed,"some string" foo_dir/bar_filename.xml,failed,"another string" foo_dir/foobar.xml,passed,"string"

do
<some bash script>
done
```

As you can see what I'm iterating through in the for loop is all on 1 line. That is quite annoying. I would like to be able to place all elements that are being iterated on separate lines like this (easier to read and change):

I have already tried below and it doesn't seem to work.

```
for i in foo_dir/foo_filename.xml,passed,"some string"
 foo_dir/bar_filename.xml,failed,"another string" 
 foo_dir/foobar.xml,passed,"string"

do
<some bash script>
done
```

Is there a way to do the above with some extra syntax or something I'm missing?

Comment: escape the newlines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you don't have trailing space after the backslash

```
for i in foo_dir/foo_filename.xml,passed,"some string" \
 foo_dir/bar_filename.xml,failed,"another string" \
 foo_dir/foobar.xml,passed,"string" 

do
<some bash script>
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Define an array first.

```
things=(
  foo_dir/foo_filename.xml,passed,"some string"
  foo_dir/bar_filename.xml,failed,"another string"
  foo_dir/foobar.xml,passed,"string"
)

for i in "${things[@]}"
do
  <some bash script>
done
```